# How to close the selected window via keyboard while in gnome-shell overview mode?

Tags: gnome, keyboard-shortcuts, gnome-shell

Press <kbd>Super</kbd>. 
You can browse the windows by <kbd>TAB</kbd>. 
I am thinking how to you can close the window without mouse or touchpad. 
Unsuccessful attempts

- <kbd>backspace</kbd>
- <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f4</kbd> (Tyler's proposal)

The feature does not exist as default in the system based on C.W.'s comment. 
To have a terminal command to make the change would be great in the system settings. 
You can open and visualise the Gonme settings by `gnome-control-center` in Terminal, where I cannot find *Shortcuts* and *Windows*, see Fig. 1-2.

Fig. 1 Only two menu settings in Windows, not corresponding the feature wanted, 
Fig. 2 No *Shortcuts* menu there

[image]

[image]

Tested on both X11 and Wayland 1.12 so there is no such a feature by default.

OS: Debian 9.1
Window manager: Gnome 3.22 on X11 and Wayland 1.12

Comment: Go to "All Settings/Keyboard/Shortcuts/Windows/" search for Close window entry (i think default is Super+L)

Comment: @C.W. I cannot find the setting. To have a terminal command for the change would be great.

Comment: have you considered to install `gnome-control-center` or is it already installed? If unsure, try to start it from terminal.
I admit i don't know a working terminal command to change the keyboard shortcut settings.

Comment: @C.W. Yes, it is the graphical control center, the one which I am using but no Shortcuts or Windows there.

Comment: is your `gnome-control-center` up to date? Try updating or reinstalling it. My live-image of Debian got many more windows entrys.

Comment: @C.W. - it has nothing to do with the control center - there is no keyboard shortcut for this operation - IOW the `Alt+F4` is for closing windows when in regular mode. In overview mode, as far as I know, you can only do it via mouse/touchpad. Nothing stopping Leo to post a feature request on their bug tracker / mailing list...

Answer (score 3):

After looking at all the possible keybindings using

```
gsettings list-keys org.gnome.desktop.wm.keybindings
```

and looking through the files in:

```
/usr/share/gnome-control-centre/keybindings/
```

It would seem that this function has not been developed for the Gnome default Windows Manager (mutter).
Note: running Fedora 26 with Gnome 3

Comment: So you propose me that the feature is not existing in Gnome 3.22 at the moment.

Comment: Correct, it is not in the current version of Gnome. It may be possible for someone to figure out what the script/function is behind the close button present in that view and map a key to that if it is necessary, however it might be worth requesting the feature at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/enter_bug.cgi if you don't get a better answer. Hopefully someone who knows gnome better comes up with a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I found is [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/804/close-windows-in-overview-with-ctrlclick/), but it allow only closing using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Mouse click</kbd>. Doesn't allow keyboard without mouse.

When you install it to Gnome, you can view source code in file
`~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/ctrl-click-close@nohum.github.com/extension.js` or [here on Github](https://github.com/nohum/gnome-shell-extension-ctrl-click-close/blob/master/ctrl-click-close%40nohum.github.com/extension.js).

I have workaround in my head, but I don't have enough experience to realize it. (sorry) You should ask some *Extension guru* or study [Extension tutorials](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions/StepByStepTutorial).

Extension mentioned above (**`line 42`**) uses injection to function event `'_onClicked'`. Than few lines below there is code `this.emit('close-requested');` on **`line 45`**, which in my opinion close window in overview. So you should somehow change this event injection to some event when enter is pressed. This will probably allow you use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> for closing. But this is only my assumption.

Answer (score 0):

I started your Debian version from a live CD.

In "All Settings/Keyboard/Windows/" i found the `Close window`-shortcut as `Alt+F4`.

So now i am wondering, do you have a fresh installation or did you customized your debian already?
Do you have the newest version (1:3.22.2-3)?

**EDIT: I missunderstood the question, you don't want to close a single displayed window, but a selected window while browsing all opend windows.**

[image]

Comment: As already pointed out in comments above, the `Alt+F4` shortcut **does not work when in overview mode** ...

Answer (score 0):

I found another extension called [AATWS - Advanced Alt-Tab Window Switcher](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4412/advanced-alttab-window-switcher/). There's to much settings that you can do, including bindings another keys to some special functions, in this case I'm using <kbd>q</kbd> key to close Tab.

Furthemore you can switch your dock, the behavior of some window, fix any tab in the main screen and also more. By default it changes a little bit the styles of dock or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, but you can deactivate everything and just use keybinds.

For someone who's looking for a official solution I think that's not possible yet.